# Does CUDA offer future-like functionality?

Tags: c++, cuda, future

I want to create a parallel procession CUDA/C++ application that does many functional operations concurrently. I want to be able to create a thread in CUDA that acts as the hub for assigning tasks and creates futures(if at all possible) that will do time consuming mathematical calculations in parallel. Does the CUDA library support this?

Edit for clarification: The thread I want to act as a hub would be created on the host CPU, and the tasks that it creates and manages would be created on the GPU device. I believe it would be possible for the CPU to checking the values of thousands of futures in sequence and assigning them new tasks as they finish. If this is possible, could the answer please reference or create a specific example of how I would be able to do this.

Comment: "future-like functionality" is an interesting (and confusing) concept. `creates futures`? What does this mean? Creating futures for what?

Comment: I want to be able to define an `std::future` and have the tasks that it runs be executed on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On re-reading your question, it appears you are asking about whether this can be done on the GPU. Yes it can, but with some very severe restrictions. CUDA harware supports atomic compare-and-swap.  There are examples in the literature of using this and other atomic instructions to implement locks and condition variables, as well as lock-free data structures.  Some reading to get you started:

- http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.4623v1
- http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~bapic/lic_thesis_bapi.pdf
- http://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.2757.pdf
- https://www.researchgate.net/publication/275603769_Toward_Concurrent_Lock-Free_Queues_on_GPUs

Bottom line is: you have to roll your own implementation of futures.  Also, any waiting thread will have to spin-wait, since there's no analog of host-side yielding.

My original answer, with the understanding you were asking about support for futures on the host side with CUDA:

Yes. Recent versions of CUDA support C++11 and CUDA has supported multiple host threads for some time.  So you can wrap a CUDA kernel call with `std::async`.

One aspect you may want to consider is that CUDA will create a thread-local context for each thread in which CUDA functions are accessed.  Depending on the implementation of `std::async` in your C++ library, you may incur severe overhead if you end up creating a new context for each `std::async` call.

Finally, CUDA calls are already asynchronous, i.e. you can continue processing things on the host thread while the GPU is busy.  There can sometimes be a benefit to pipelining kernel calls.  You can also use the CUDA events API to coordinate multiple asynchronous CUDA activities within a single thread. In some sense the CUDA implementation is already doing what you are possibly proposing with `std::future`.  I would recommend first convincing yourself you cannot manage with a single host thread before venturing into multi-threaded territory, which can sometimes bring a host of non-CUDA related problems.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This link should help you as a direct reference to NVidia's CUDA Toolkit API Documentation. NOTE: their website address may be subject to change.

[CUDA Toolkit Documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/#axzz43DtLFopf)

After reading through some of the documentation it appears that CUDA is designed for Multithreaded and Parallel Programing by its own machine architecture along with its own CUDA environment and compiler. Since modern GPUs have been designed specifically for this purpose due to the high volume of data processing, specifically image, graphics, video processing, it is easy to conclude that this is done behind the scenes within the architecture of a CUDA device.

While reading their specs about support for the C++ language they do include support for a majority of the language but some of it may be restricted to only the host and not available to the device or kernel code where these are respectively defined as `__host__ __device__ __global__`. I'm not all that familiar with CUDA currently but this is what I was able to gather from reading the API docs that I provided as a reference in the link above.

You had asked this:

> I want to create a parallel procession CUDA/C++ application that does many functional operations concurrently. I want to be able to create a thread in CUDA that acts as the hub for assigning tasks and creates futures(if at all possible) that will do time consuming mathematical calculations in parallel. Does the CUDA library support this?

To answer your question, I think the design of the architecture speaks for itself, where you can break down your code to work on multiple threads within multiple blocks to a grid. Parallelism and multithreading is at the core of how their GPU is designed along with its API and compiler. However, the only thing that I was not able to find any information on was the use of futures or promises. So it may depend on your project's overall method of design of how you would implement this. I'm sure that you would be able to create an object on the host side that would encapsulate your device threads and would manage the synchronization and concurrency of futures and promises, but as to implementing these on the device or kernel side I was not able to find any direct answer or representation from their documentation to say one way or another. So other than the consideration of your request to use c++ futures, you asked if the CUDA Library or API supports what you would like to do, for everything else I would have to say that it already does by design.